How do I disconnect my domain from the old website and connect it to the new website?
I want to build a completely new website with a different host than the one I am using now (Wordpress) instead of migrating it. How do I disassociate my domain (which I own) from the old website and transfer it to the new website?

The very simple answer is "Make changes in your DNS".  Unpacking this answer -
There are multiple moving parts to hosting your website.  I'm simplifying help you focus here but as an overview, the layers involved are -
Domain Registration -> DNS -> Website
Very often your Domain registration and DNS are done by the same provider, however it is not uncommon for a different party to provide your DNS to your registration - sometimes this will be your IT company, web hosting, brand/asset management or email provider.   You need to establish who handles your DNS   - You can often do this by looking at the registrar and looking at what the nameservers are set to.
Once you know the nameservers, its a simple matter of updating the zone file (ie data in the nameserver).   You do want someone who knows what they are doing to guide you here because things can break if you do it wrong.  Note that changes made to DNS do not take effect everywhere immediately - depending on a whole lot of factors it could take anything from 10 minutes to a few days to update.
Once you have updated the DNS and migrated to the new website, don't forget to tell your old web hosting provider you don't need their services anymore - they will probably continue to bill until you provide notice as they will not usually know when you have made the change.
IF YOUR REGISTRAR OR DNS IS HELD WITH YOUR WEB HOSTING PROVIDER -
You will likely want to move the registration and DNS records away from your old provider to a new provider.  Again, lots of options.  For most domains you will want 2 things -

A copy of the zone file so you can rebuild it with your new provider (ie so emails don't break for example).  For simple cases someone who knows what they are doing can recreate it from public records - but there in some cases this will not work 100%.

A copy of the Auth Code (sometimes called EPP code or UDAI or similar). Generally you get this code from your old domain registrar, and then use it with your new registrar - and often its best to set up your domain with their nameservers.     You will need to ensure you update your nameservers if appropriate.


